# Control voltage to heat resistor using PID

Tags: voltage, power, resistors, pid-controller

I have a question about PIDs. I have a 2.2 kW heat resistor powered from 220 Vac. I would like to control the resistor using PID.

As I can see the most PID based control systems are using a Solid State Relay (SSR). Therefore, I conclude that these systems produce a smart on/off sequence based on PID parameters.

I would like to ask you if I can control the voltage across the heat resistor with a PID system i.e. not just on/off control. This will control the power and therefore the heat produced. Do you have any proposal?

Excuse me if the question is trivial.

Comment: The questions is unclear. The relay controls the ac voltage. The pid just turns it on and off according to its transfer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control a resistive load like a heater in an actual *proportional* way, you would typical do so with a TRIAC driver.

But while a phase cutting TRIAC "sort of" varies the voltage in the sense that it may prevent the load from ever seeing the peak part of the waveform, in reality what it mostly does is create a form of pulse width modulation, at the AC line frequency rate - you are turning the heater on and off, but at a very rapid rate.

Heaters and whatever they are heating tend to have a substantial thermal time constant.  Which is to say, that they take a while to heat up and cool down.

In practice this means that many heater controllers simply implement on/off control at a time scale humans can actual notice by sound or sometimes sight, if not by effect.

But if you want to tightly control temperature in a small range, then something like a TRIAC could be worthwhile.  Beware that as the TRIAC itself is implicitly mains connected, this is tricky to do right.  If you go down this path in a DIY project, at bare minimum make sure that both your zero cross detection and your TRIAC driver use optoisolators - conventional for the first, probably opto-TRIAC to drive the power TRIAC for the second.

You then have the choice between using a phase-cutting scheme as needed for something with a short time constant like a light or universal motor, or perhaps using a simpler scheme where you either power or do not power the heater for an entire half-period of the AC waveform at a time.  The latter is electrically "cleaner" since you switch only at the zero crossing point when a resistive load is drawing no current.

It's not really clear that this kind of fine scale control and all of its complexity is going to be very useful for your goal, vs getting a quality solid state relay and simply commanding it on or off on the timescale of a moderate fraction of a second.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I want to build a boiler which after sometime will maintain the temperature to a target (e.g 75 Celcius). So how can I built a TRIAC (e.g SCR) controlled by PID? As I can see the most TRIAC driver are ajdusted by hand.

Comment: You mean a water heater, not a "boiler" and such things have such huge thermal time constants you could switch it on and off with even a mechanical relay on the order of seconds.  You don't need any of this fancy stuff, and shouldn't go there due to the complications of doing so safely.  Look at actual hot water heater thermostats...

Comment: Can you explain more the " thermal time constants"? Thus, you propose to use a PID with just an on/off relay without adjusting the voltage? For some reason, I am thinking as a better choice to adjust voltage to avoid on/off. For example why in A/C system the use inverters to avoid start stop? (forgive my ignorance)

Comment: Thermal time constant simply means it takes time to heat up and cool down - human scale time.  Your classic cooking range burner you can hear click on and off, a water heater and the water inside have far more mass and respond even more slowly than a frying pan on a burner.   Soft starting A/C compressor motors is an entirely different mechanical issue.

Comment: So a PID with an SSR is enough for my application. Correct? How can I decide the P, I, D parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I've mostly controlled itty bitty clean stuff, not industrial things.  The one place I've seen a PID controller used to drive a relay* was for an environmental chamber -- in that case, the on/off cycle was fixed at about ten seconds, and the duration of the relay closure each cycle was controlled by the PID controller.

You could do the same thing with a SSR.  Just choose a period that's fast enough so that the on/off cycling of the heater doesn't cause too much temperature excursion, and go to town.

If your goal is just to achieve stand-alone temperature control, you ought to be able to buy an off-the-shelf temperature controller that'll do all of this for you, possibly including tuning the PID loop.

* It was an honest-to-gosh **relay** that opened and closed with a "thunk" -- it was 20 years ago, and the chamber was probably 20 years old then.

Comment: Yes, this is true, If I buy a commersial PID solution the tuning will be easier. I am not sure what item is best for my application

Answer (score 0):

Most temperature controls can use time proportioning, the time cycle is maybe 20 seconds long with a mechanical contactor and can be shorter with a zero-voltage-switching SSR, as low as a couple seconds. That's try of plastics machinery and many ovens.

Phase control is generally reserved for applications where the actuator (eg. heater) response time is so fast that time proportioning does not work well, so it's worth putting up with the EMI and nonlinearity of phase control. An example where phase control might be called for is heating of air with exposed heater coils- the cycle time would be long enough that the air temperature pulsates unacceptably for some applications.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give some example bout phase control and how can be applied?

Comment: Can you read the second paragraph?

Comment: I read it. For some reason it was not visible in my phone.